# How to clear output of function call in VIM?

Tags: vim

I know my question title is not explanatory enough so let me try to explain.

I created a `vim function` that displays my current battery state. My function is as follows:

```
function! BatteryStatus()

     let l:status = system("~/battery_status.sh")
     echo join(split(l:status))

endfunction
```

I have mapped the above function as `nnoremap <F3> :call BatteryStatus()<cr>`. Now, when I press `F3` it displays my battery status as `Discharging, 56%, 05:01:42 remaining` which is my required output but my question is how do I make the above output disappear.

Currently what happens is after function call it continuously displays the output and I have to manually use `:echo` to clear the command window(`:`).

So, what necessary changes are to be made in my function so that I can achieve toggle like behaviour.

**battery_status.sh**

```
acpi | awk -F ": " '{print $2}'
```

PS: This is part of a learning exercise. So, please don't suggest alternative `vim scripts`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplistic straightforward way to toggling the output:

```
let s:battery_status_output_flag = "show"

function! BatteryStatus()

    if s:battery_status_output_flag == "show"
        let l:status = system("~/battery_status.sh")
        echo join(split(l:status))
        let s:battery_status_output_flag = "clear"
    else
        echo ""
        let s:battery_status_output_flag = "show"
    endif

endfunction
```

Note `s:` prefix, see `:help script-variable`

Answer (score 2):

You can define a `autocmd`:

```
:au CursorHold * redraw!
```

Vim redraws itself 4 sec (set by `updatetime` option) after it's idle.

Answer (score 2):

```
vim
function! pseudocl#render#clear()
  echon "\r\r"
  echon ''
endfunction
```

Comment: you can use echon "\r\r" echon ' '

Comment: Thanks this was perfect. redraw! was so flickery for my purposes. I'm surprised theirs no way to just clear the command line besides this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>L</kbd> to clear the message on the status
line.